# i need help moving my player in the canvas

Tags: javascript, html

i can't get the image to move in the canvas. tried many things and failed please help

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
canvas.width  = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";
```

start here

```
var player = function(img){
    x=10,
    y=10,
    width=20,
    height=20

}
```

add the player

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);

function game(){
    update();
    render();
}

function update(){
    if(keys[37]) player.y--;
    if(keys[38]) player.y++;
    if(keys[39]) player.x--;
    if(keys[40]) player.x++;

};
```

i need to know how to get the player to move

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your code logic. First, use requestAnimationFrame() to register method to be fired that will render/update your canvas automatically only when it is needed. Read the basic details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).
I do not know how your logic is implemented, the source you posted is rather incomplete, but suggesting you change var player into object instead of function (so player.x++ will work):

```
function render() {
  //your render code here
  player1.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function Player(img){
  this.x = 10;
  this.y = 10;
  this.height = 20;
  this.width = 20;
  this.img = img;
}

Player.prototype.draw = function() {
  canvas.drawImage(this.img);
};

//create instance of Player
player1 = new Player(handleToYourPlayerImage);

// start it
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

(Don't forget to add your keyboard handling code to that.)